# entity number formating in phalcon form volt

Tags: forms, number-formatting, phalcon, volt

**Problem** :

I want to render form text with formatting value.

**Case**

> [input:text]  // this is text input
>
> [5000] // this is my text input without `number_format()`
>
> [5.000] // this is my goals

**Code :**

```
$protQty   = new Text('protQty',[
    'placeholder'   => 'Jumlah Pesan ( Hanya Angka ) ',
    'class'         => 'form-control ',
    'value'         => number_format($entity->protQty,0,",","."), //unworking code
    'readonly'      => true
]);
$protQty->setLabel('Jumlah Permintaan');
$this->add($protQty);
```

Comment: What output are you getting now? Your `number_format`, as is, should produce the desired output.

Comment: @Timothy, hello u again! :D
in short answer i want output 5.000 as i explain above, but that's my code doesn't work on `number_format()`-ing  the `$entity->protQty`.

Comment: What value is hiding behind `$entity->protQty`, could you `var_dump` and check please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify the entity. Field value is overwritten if entity is available.

Do the following:

```
$entity->protQty = number_format($entity->protQty, 0, ",", ".");

$protQty = new Text('protQty',[
    'placeholder' => 'Jumlah Pesan ( Hanya Angka ) ',
    'class' => 'form-control ',
    // Not needed anymore
    // 'value' => number_format($entity->protQty,0,",","."), //unworking code
    'readonly' => true
]);
```

Other option would be to use getters/setters in your model to always output the data in the desired format.